# Searching for a fireproof sponge?

Tags: heat, plastics

(I know this is a bit off topic, but I don't know where else to ask. If you know a better StackExchange site, please tell me)

I'm working on a project, and I want to basically create a "flaming sail". For this, I'm planning to drench a cloth in methanol and then lighting it, and for this, I need a fabric that both retains a lot of moisture and is flame proof, as this should be reusable.

Comment: https://www.mscdirect.com/browse/tnpla/06641153?cid=ppc-google-New+-+Welding+%26+Soldering+-+PLA_s1SU9UK6M___164124449405_c_S&mkwid=s1SU9UK6M%7cdc&pcrid=164124449405&rd=k&product_id=06641153&gclid=CjwKCAiA-_L9BRBQEiwA-bm5fkdEzExtD89KdCgcNdt7GYiCQovemOQ0xRNz67h4L4w0lVb1y9PcHhoCVksQAvD_BwE  Asbestos fabric might work but the downside to experimenting at home with asbestos just is not worth it.  So why post this suggesting?  I hope it a) directs you to something that will work and b) keeps you away from something that is just not worth doing.

Comment: How large? Can you use a metal fabric?

Comment: Perhaps glass wool or the glass/ceramic tape used by glassblowers as a safe asbestos substitute.

Comment: Mix the methanol with water, perhaps 50/50%, and most fabrics will be cooled by evaporation and not burn. BTW, add a *little* salt, copper sulfate, lithium chloride or other salts with bright spectral lines to make the flames colorful.

Comment: You could try a fiberglass or carbon fiber welding blanket.  Here's an example: https://www.harborfreight.com/6-ft-x-8-ft-fiberglass-welding-blanket-95015.html  One doesn't normally think of fiberglass as being absorbent but, with the right weave, it could have enough channels to absorb methanol via capillary action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to imbue with Sodium bicarbonate. The action of [heating the Baking Soda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_bicarbonate), $\ce{NaHCO3}$, as a powder absorbs energy while releasing $\ce{H2O}$ and $\ce{CO2}$ to assist in retarding the flame per the reaction:

$\ce{2 NaHCO3 (s) ->  Na2CO3 (s) + H2O (l) +  CO2 (g)}$

Also, lesser-known, but important [per a source](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/245209080_Fire_retardancy_impact_of_sodium_bicarbonate_on_ligno-cellulosic_materials#:%7E:text=Abstract,and%20combustion%20has%20been%20investigated.&text=Thus%2C%20sodium%20bicarbonate%20decreases%20the,forest%20species%20(promotion%20effect)), to quote:

> Even though the exact modes of action are not well established, the $\ce{NaOH}$ formed may promote catalytic recombination of the radical species needed for flame propagation, causing the flames to extinguish [23]

Note, it is known that heating Sodium carbonate in the presence of $\ce{H2O}$ can be a source of $\ce{NaOH}$ (see [comments here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Can_someone_explain_to_me_how_to_regenerate_NaOH_from_Na2CO3_to_NaOH_again_because_i_use_NaOH_to_purify_CO2_from_Biogas_product)) to facilitate the above cited mechanism.

So, safe inexpensive Baking Soda is my recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

Fiberfrax is the standard material for high temperatures in refinery, chem. plants, etc. There are also other brands , all readily available on the net. Ads do not give detailed composition other than "alumina and silica" .  Fiberglasses may not have  high melting /softening temperatures. There are higher temperature fibers like thoria, but are expensive and not easy to find.